# What will be the $product->getFinalPrice()?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

A configurable product having prices as `[10,12,15,15]`.

What will be output of the `$product->getFinalPrice()` ?

Comment: If this is an exam question and you are answering according to theory - usually lowest price

Comment: For configurable products, each child product's base price is a final price.  If it has any special prices then that will be subtracted on final price.

Comment: And for your question, if you skip checking child products and  directly call like this => $product->getFinalPrice()  you will get only a first child product price "10"

Answer (score 1):

If you call directly like this, You will get only a first child product price.

```
$product->getFinalPrice()
```

It will return 10.

Comment: Because it's lowest?